# What is the best way to access the second to last value in an R data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data.frame called SLV and I apply the tail()function. I will get this:

```
> tail(SLV)

       SLV.Open SLV.High SLV.Low SLV.Close SLV.Volume SLV.Adjusted
2010-12-06    28.99    29.64   28.88     29.51   57561800        29.51
2010-12-07    29.95    30.00   28.03     28.08   69143800        28.08
2010-12-08    28.33    28.46   27.34     27.70   58203800        27.70
2010-12-09    28.10    28.36   27.83     28.03   36759200        28.03
2010-12-10    27.80    28.11   27.38     27.98   30602700        27.98
2010-12-13    28.84    29.04   28.59     28.87   25901800        28.87
```

tail() defaults to the last 6 values, but it's easy to get just the last 1 value.

```
>tail(SLV, n=1)

       SLV.Open SLV.High SLV.Low SLV.Close SLV.Volume SLV.Adjusted
2010-12-13    28.84    29.04   28.59     28.87   25901800        28.87
```

But what is the best way to return the second to last day? In our SLV example, it would be the line that is dated 2010-12-10.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
head(tail(SLV, n=2), n=1)
```

or

```
SLV[nrow(SLV)-1,]
```

will do it.

Comment: I think that second solution is proper way to do the task. The first is too complicated, when you look on underlying code in `head` and `tail`.

Comment: +1 for head/tail, regardless of their implementation - they are robust in my experience

Comment: `SLV[nrow(SLV)-1,]` is much faster. And if an specific column was the target, `SLV$SLV.Open[nrow(SLV)-1]` is faster than `SLV[nrow(SLV)-1,"SLV.Open"]`

Answer (score 9):

For yet another alternative:

```
tail(SLV,2)[-2]
```

Answer (score 3):

head(tail(SLV, n=2), n=1)

Answer (score 0):

Very slightly more general than SLV[nrow(SLV)-1,]:

```
SLV[rev(1:nrow(SLV))[2],]
```

Literal [2] can be replaced with a vector which is possibly neater if more than one row is required.

Comment: Instead or `rev(1:nrow(SLV))` you could use `(nrow(SLV):1)`.