# Access second to last element of vectors nested in list in R

Tags: r, list, indexing

*[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445873/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-the-second-to-last-value-in-an-r-data-frame?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) exist, but don't respond my specific question.

In a nested list, what's an elegant way of accessing the second to last element of each vector. Take the following list:

```
l <- list(c("a","b","c"),c("c","d","e","f"))
```

How do I produce a new list (or vector) which contains the second to last element of each vector in list `l`? The output should look like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "b"

[[2]]
[1] "e"
```

I access the last element of each vector via `lapply(l,dplyr::last)`, but not sure how to select the second to last elements. Much appreciated.

Comment: Here's a base R method: `lapply(l, function(x) tail(head(x, -1L), 1L))`

Comment: If you want to stick with `dplyr`, just use `nth`: `lapply(l, dplyr::nth,-2)`.

Comment: These are good alternatives. Maybe you can post them as answers. I ended using the dplyr alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
l <- list(c("a","b","c"),c("c","d","e","f"))
lapply(l, function(x) x[length(x) -1])
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "e"
```